# When I write a python script to run Devenv with configure "Debug|Win32" it does nothing

Tags: python, subprocess

**Update:** When I use the `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, the problem is solved - does anybody know what's the cause? And there came another problem: I can't seem to find a way to control the output... Is there a way to redirect the output from `subprocess.call` to a string or something like that? Thanks!

I'm trying to use `Devenv` to build projects, and it runs just fine when i type it in command prompt like `devenv A.sln /build "Debug|Win32"` - but when I use a python to run it using `Popen(cmd,shell=true)` where `cmd` is the same line as above, it shows nothing. If I remove the `|`, change it to `"Debug"` only, it works....

Does anybody know why this happens? I've tried putting a `\` before `|`, but still nothing happened..

This is the code I am using:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = ' "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv" solution.sln /build "Debug|Win32" '

sys.stdout.flush()
p = Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
lines = []
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    lines.append(line)
out = string.join(lines)
print out
if out.strip():
    print out.strip('\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

...which doesn't work, however, if I swap `Debug|Win32` with `Debug`, it works perfectly..

Thanks for every comment here

Comment: Just a hunch that popped in my head, which popen did you use/ can you show the import statement?

Comment: Sure, it's:

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p = Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

where cmd is something like '"..(path)/devenv" solution /build "Debug|Win32" ...
it seems the | sign makes the whole command being ignored...

Comment: I found out that creating a compile.bat file on the fly in Python, which contains the entire `devenv.com` command, and then running that compile.bat from Python using `Popen` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `shell = False` is used, it will treat the string as a single command, so you need to pass the command/arugments as a list.. Something like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = [
    r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv", # in raw r"blah" string, you don't need to escape backslashes
    "solution.sln",
    "/build",
    "Debug|Win32"
]

p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out = p.stdout.read() # reads full output into string, including line breaks

print out
```

Comment: Actually the list of arguments doesn't work for me - when I run it, it keeps showing devenv's help dialog, which should mean only the first argument was called.
However, you've got right sense with the shell argument - it turned out when I disable the shell = True, the original command line works out perfectly. There must be different meaning for | with shell option I guess.
Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between `devenv.exe` and `devenv.com`, both of which are executable and live in the same directory (sigh). The command lines used in the question and some answers don't say which they want so I'm not sure which will get used.

If you want to call from the command line then you need to ensure you use `devenv.com`, otherwise you're likely to get a GUI popping up. I think this might be the cause of some (but not all) of the confusion.

Comment: this worked for me.  I changed 'devenv' above to 'devenv.com' and it all started working.

Answer (score 1):

See section 17.1.5.1. in the python documentation.

On Windows, Python automatically adds the double quotes around the project configuration argument i.e Debug|win32 is passed as "Debug|win32" to devenv. You DON'T need to add the double quotes and you DON'T need to pass shell=True to Popen.

Use ProcMon to view the argument string passed to devenv.

Answer (score 0):

try double quoting like: 'devenv A.sln /build "Debug|Win32"'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows' shell is taking that `|` as a pipe (despite the quotes and escapes). Have you tried `shell=False` instead?

Comment: When I set shell to False, I can't seem to get any output so cannot make sure if it's working or not. Can you tell me how to get output when shell=False? Thanks

Comment: It's a mystery -- please show us the whole snippet of code, otherwise it will no doubt stay one;-).

Comment: It turned out it's the shell option caused the problem. Not sure why I wasn't able to get the output at first tho. Thanks!!